# Usage of "to both of whom"

Tags: whom

I am writing a short formal acknowledgement in a paper, and I would like to thank two people at the same time. The phrase I'm using is essentially:

> Coffee was paid for by John and Anna, to both of whom I express my sincere gratitude.

I am not sure if the expression "to both of whom" is correct. Should it be "to whom both"? Maybe a small variation of the phrasing would work, but I can't think of any that is short and formal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Coffee was paid for by John and Anna, to **both of whom** I express my
>   sincere gratitude.

is the correct of the two sentences you pose.

**both**  [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/21867?rskey=TRNW0u&result=2&isAdvanced=true#eid16266937)

> With a plural pronoun (denoting the members of a **pair**).
>   Immediately following (or in early use preceding) a subject or object
>   pronoun. Also in both which. Cf. sense C. 3, and both of us, **both of
>   whom**, etc., at sense

To use **to whom both** in your sentence:

> Coffee was paid for by John and Anna, **to whom both** I and my companion
>   express sincere gratitude.

Answer (score 1):

It could not be “to whom both”. If the clause were not a relative clause, you would write something like “I express my sincere gratitude to both of them.” You can turn it into a relative clause by replacing “them” with the relative pronoun “whom”, which needs to be “fronted”—placed at the start of the clause. But if you wrote *”whom I express my sincere gratitude to both of,” the preposition “of” would be “stranded”—something that is possible in some sentences, but not I think here. So other things move with the relative pronoun (this is called “pied-piping”). If we just moved the “of”, we would get “of whom I express my sincere gratitude to both.” This sounds a bit better to me, but I think that it still sounds worse than the option you mentioned with pier-piping of the phrase “to both of whom”—“to both of whom I express my sincere gratitude.”

Pied-piping is fairly formal, but you said that the context of the sentence is supposed to be formal.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the word both. Whom is singular and plural, just the same as you is.

“Coffee was paid for by John and Anna, to whom I expressed my sincere gratitude.”

Comment: Dropping "both" is worse, because it gives the impression that the writer thanked only Anna.